# calling a method on a param before I create a record in rails/ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In the create method of my link controller I call the following to make a new link then call a method on the url attribute to remove something:

```
@link = Link.new(params[:link])
@link.url = strip_http(@link.url)
```

Is there a way to combine these two statements so i can call the strip_http method on the url param before/as I send it to the database? Feels more efficient and I could reduce my database calls by one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually there won't be any database call while you're not calling `save` or `create`on your object.
But you could do something like this:

```
params[:link][:url] = strip_http(params[:link][:url])
@link = Link.create(params[:link])
```

## **A better solution would be**

To use a callback on your model:

```
class Link < Activerecord::Base
  before_save :strip_http

  def strip_http
    ...
  end
end
```

And then in your controller action:

```
@link = Link.create(params[:link])
```

Nothing else to do in that case. : )

Comment: Thanks Sparda, can you explain what I'm doing by changing link.new to link.create in the create controller? Also does before_save also get called on record updates as well if someone was to update that field later on. I'm also not sure what you mean by no database call unless save/create. When does the data get sent to the DB as it appears to be recording all my changes and I'm not using create or save. Thanks.

Comment: Well, `Link.new()` initializes a new Link object, that means your object exists but is not persisted. `Link.save()` on the other hand, persists your object in db. Using `Link.new()` then `Link.save()` is equivalent to using `Link.create()`. `before_save` will be triggered every time your Link object is persisted or updated, so it will work with `save()`, `create()`, `update_attributes()`, `update_attribute()`.

Comment: Thanks, I found the link.save further down so I guess everything was working as you described all along.